# Django if elif else statement

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to print the result according to the user's age selection in the form, but my if,elif and else statements are not working.

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    age_choices = (('10-12', '10-12'),
        ('13-16', '13-16'), 
        ('17-20', '17-20'),
        ('21-23','21-23'),
        )   
   age = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = age_choices)
```

```
views.py
def create_order(request):
  form = QuizForm(request.POST or None)
  if request.method == 'POST':
     quiz = Quiz.objects
     if quiz.age=='10-12':
        print("10-12")
     elif quiz.age=='13-16':
        print("13-16")
     elif quiz.age=='17-20':
        print("17-20")
     elif quiz.age=='21-23':
        print("21-23")
     else:
         return None
   context = {'form':form}

   return render(request, "manualupload.html", context)
```

Comment: @Abhijeetk431 how can that be done I'm new to django?

Comment: Right now if I select a specific age group in the form , it prints more than 1 statement of a different age group.

Comment: is it because of this line-- print("13-16)

Comment: @harryG can you share `QuizForm`? If it's a ModelForm you can use `quiz = form.save(commit=False)` to get a `Quiz` object from the form data

Answer (score 0):

`quiz = Quiz.objects` will return a django.db.models.manager.Manager object and this can be further used to fetch the objects from database belonging to that particular model. The appropriate query set will be `quiz = Quiz.objects.all()` Then you will get the list of all objects in that belong to Quiz model. Once you get list of all objects, you can get the specific object either by indexing or by filtering using a specific query that you need to look into and then for that particular object you can get the age property.

Refer to [official django documentation about creating queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/) for more information.

Comment: I hope you can see what you are doing here and what needs do be done from this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Abhijeetk431 mentioned, your issue lies in `quiz = Quiz.objects`.

If you use `type(quiz)`, you will find that it outputs `django.db.models.manager.Manager`. This is not what you want, as `age` is a property of the `Quiz` class, not the `Manager` class.

For starters, refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects).

This will return you a **Queryset list**, something akin to an Excel table. `age` is akin to the *column* in the table. To get `age`, what you want is the *row* (the actual `Quiz` object) in said table, which you can achieve using `get` or using the square brackets `[]`.

Thus, your code should look something like this:

```
Model.objects.all()[0]
```

That would return the correct object(only the first row) and allow you to get the column value.

However, further clarification will be needed though, to know exactly what your problem is aside from 'it doesn't work'. How did you know your code is not working; what did the debugger tell you?